# Sending binary data over serial port from a raspberry pi using python3 results in garbage

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, binary, serial-port

I am trying to send binary data from a raspberry pi over serial, but whenever I attempt to send in an integer, the data result is just random characters. I have correctly configured the baud rate and can successfully send strings over the serial.

I have tried using a different serial cable and all of the following:

```
ser.write((255).to_bytes(2, byteorder="little"))
ser.write(bytes([255]))
ser.write(struct.pack("B", 255))
ser.write(bytes('255', 'UTF-8'))
```

All of the above prints random characters.

I can; however, do the following:

```
ser.write(bytes('255', 'UTF-8'))
```

And that correctly prints 255, which makes me believe this is not a hardware issue.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0')
ser.baudrate = 115200

ser.write((255).to_bytes(2, byteorder="little"))
ser.write(bytes([255]))
ser.write(struct.pack("B", 255))
```

The output is the following for all three alternatives when sending an integer:

```
123456789:; 7C 7C 4B 14; | -.346::
```

And correctly 255 when sending a string.

This data is received by a PC (using a raspberry pi to USB serial cable) and test read using Tera Term from which the output is posted. The baud-rate on Tera Term is set to match the one of the PySerial instance and the correct COM was configured as well.

Comment: You seem to be only looking at and describing half of the whole picture. *"I am trying to send binary data from a raspberry pi over serial, .."* -- And to where does this data go? *"I have tried using ... all of the following: ... All of the above prints random characters"* -- You vaguely describe how data is sent, but there's nothing about how or by what this data is received. A communication link requires both ends to be configured correctly. The problem could be at either end or both ends. You neglect to describe any means used for properly receiving and handling/displaying the binary data.

Comment: This data is received by a PC and test read using Tera Term from which the output is posted. The baud-rate on Tera Term is set to match the one of the PySerial instance and the correct COM was configured as well.

Comment: TeraTerm is a terminal emulation program.  It treats the data it receives as text, i.e. ASCII code.  When TeraTerm recieves *"binary data"*, it is still going to treat it as text, hence what you call *"garbage data"*.  If you're going to send binary data, then you need a program on the other end that knows what to do with the data it receives.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same question and struggled for a while to find the answer. Even the much touted Chat-GTP failed to make sense of it :-)

What worked for me was:

```py
variable = 255
ser.write(bytes([variable]))
```

I hope this helps.